# Image to pdf conversion. pdf file is chopped for Nexus s & above resolution/size device :-

Tags: android

I am taking snap shot of current screen storing it in sd card and then converting it to pdf format. All is well if i test it for Nexus one but as i go for higher resolution devices (Nexus s,Galaxy Nexus) .The converted pdf is not showing full screen shot rather it is chopped . I have shared below the code used by me .Thanx in advance .

My Method for taking screen shot :

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
           View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
           rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
           return rootView.getDrawingCache();
        }
    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

My method for pdf conversion :-

```
void Pdfconverter() throws Exception
       {                  
            Document document=new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("mnt/sdcard/FirstPdf.pdf"));
            document.open();
            Image image = Image.getInstance (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
            document.add(new Paragraph("Heading for the Image"));
            document.add(image);               
            document.close(); 
       }
```